# How can I define the general structure of an object without adding every single one of its properties to the definition?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, structure, indexer

Let's say I have an object like the following, mapping errors names to their code and message:

`let Errors = {
    FOO: [1, 'Foo error'],
    BAR: [2, 'Bar error'],
    BAZ: [3, 'Baz error']
}`

Every property has the inferred type of `(number | string)[]`, good, but we know that the type is actually the more specific `[number, string]`. In order to let TypeScript know about it, as far as I understand, we have to do something like the following:

`let Errors = {
    FOO: [1, 'Foo error'] as [number, string],
    BAR: [2, 'Bar error'] as [number, string],
    BAZ: [3, 'Baz error'] as [number, string]
}`

Is it possible to add the proper types to all the properties in a cleaner way that avoids all these repetitions?

Comment: If you use that definition, you have to access that object property as Obj['prop']. The interface you mentioned is specifying that the object is indexable and that `number` result. I could be wrong but I don't believe it's possible to specify that type declaration allowing any property to have a specific number, maybe using proxies. You could always use `any`

Comment: Accessing Obj's properties using that notation is considered a wrong practice when you know the name of the property at design time. And also I can write any kind of string in that way without TS complaining about it, pointless.

Comment: Well what do you want? Do you want TS to be able to tell you when you've misspelt the property (`Obj.prob`, for example)? When you've missed a required property? If you want to use arbitrary properties, why bother typing it at all?

Comment: If "you know the name of the property at design time" then you need to put that name into the interface, that's the whole point. It might be tedious at times but then you get the benefits that typescript provides.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In short I want to write a **general** type definition for all the properties, without the need to add said definition to every single property, which may be tens or more. By "arbitrary" I don't mean that any kind of property can be added to the object, but only those of its general type.

Comment: @NitzanTomer that's exactly the point of my question. Asking if there's a way to avoid this tedious task by writing the type of all properties once.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Can you please add a better example in your question to clarify?

Comment: Sure, I've edited my post, now it should be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to tell the compiler that all of the properties have the same type.

You can use a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) to make it a bit better:

```
type ErrorInfo = [number, string];

let Errors = {
    FOO: [1, 'Foo error'] as ErrorInfo,
    BAR: [2, 'Bar error'] as ErrorInfo,
    BAZ: [3, 'Baz error'] as ErrorInfo
};
```

Another option is to have a type for your `Errors`:

```
type ErrorInfo = [number, string];

interface ErrorMap = {
    FOO: ErrorInfo;
    BAR: ErrorInfo;
    BAZ: ErrorInfo;
}

let Errors: ErrorMap = {
    FOO: [1, 'Foo error'],
    BAR: [2, 'Bar error'],
    BAZ: [3, 'Baz error']
};
```

There's defiantly a repetition here, but it makes a good separation between the interface and the actual runtime value.